# How do I force an option to be selected from my select menu in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html-select, selected, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Using JQuery 1.11, I’m having trouble forcing a option to be selected.  I know the text of the option, and so I’m using

```
.find('option[text="Canada"]')
```

but my expression is not locating the item, despite the fact that in the console (output listed below), you can clearly see there is an option that reads “Canada”.

```
> $('.countryField')
[<select id=​"user[address]​_country" name=​"user[address]​[country]​" class=​"countryField select-hidden">​…​</select>​<option value=​"0">​-- Select --​</option>​<option value=​"38">​Canada​</option>​…​<option value=​"249">​Zimbabwe​</option>​</select>​]
> $('.countryField').find('option[text="Canada"]')
[]
```

What am I doing wrong?  Ultimately, I want to have the “selected” attribute enabled for the option with the given text (and have all the other options have no “selected” attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the below.

```
$(".countryField option").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() == "Canada")
    $(this).attr("selected","selected");
});


$(".countryField option[value='Canada']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: So this will select the option with the text but will it also unselect all other options?

Comment: If your drop down is single select then the answer is yes

Comment: It is a single select, but I'm not finding what you're sayhing above to be true.  That is, the attribute 'selected="selected"' remains on the option that was previously selected.

Comment: Then can you post your code, so that it's easy for me to comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply [jQuery val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to select your element.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#speed").selectmenu();

  // select the Canada option
  $("#speed").val('Canada');
  $("#speed").selectmenu('refresh');
  
  // instead if you need to get the option with Canada text
  var selectedEle = $("#speed option").filter(function(i, e) {return $(e).text() == 'Canada';});
  console.log(selectedEle[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```css
#speed {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<select name="speed" id="speed">
    <option>Slower</option>
    <option>Slow</option>
    <option selected="selected">Medium</option>
    <option>Fast</option>
    <option>Faster</option>
    <option>Canada</option>
</select>
```